# How do I query a SQL Server database with a list of parameters in Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a list of objects with various properties. I want to query a database using these properties and get a result list back.

This is what I've tried:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Animal>> GetAnimalsFromAttributesAsync(IEnumerable<AnimalInfo> attributeSets)
{
    using (var myDB = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await myDB.OpenAsync();
        var results = new List<Animal>();

        foreach (var attributeSet in attributeSets)
        {
            var sql = @"select AnimalID, AnimalTypeID, AnimalColor
                        from Animals
                        where AnimalTypeID = @AnimalTypeID 
                          and AnimalColorID = @AnimalColorID";

            var result = myDB.Query<Animal>(sql, attributeSet);
            results.AddRange(result);
        }

        return results
    }
}
```

This works ok for small numbers of properties. But if I have a lot of properties, then I get this error:

> Error: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you really query the database with a where clause with 2k parameters at once?

Comment: Hi - what is `AnimalInfo` here? I'm struggling to see why it is causing a parameter explosion (context: I'm the primary dapper author)

Comment: Try using SQL "in" operator and provide your IDs as a an array.

Comment: @IsmarMujagic the query here is using `=` - it *should* be fine...

Comment: something to try: `var result = myDB.Query<Animal>(sql, new { attributeSet.AnimalTypeId, attributeSet.AnimalColorID });` - should make it impossible for anything too bizarre to happen

Comment: @gsharp Yeah, there are 3000 AnimalInfos!

Comment: @MarcGravell What I'm saying is that he can use one query with "IN" instead of shooting at the database from foreach..

Comment: @Marc Gravell what if I just have a lot of AnimalInfo's. I think the query itself is working fine. Just that I'm trying to query too much. I guess I need to rethink how I do this.

Comment: @IsmarMujagic how would that look like? The problem is I have 2 properties that need to match at the same time.

Comment: @Alexander Ah OK, "need to match at the same time" makes it different then. However the point is, I would avoid this querying inside foreach. Maybe you can query entries from the database using some general filter to get some set which you can then in-memory filter further with your Color and Type IDs. Another approach would be to move the logic to the database level if possible, but I don't know how do you supply your attributeSets..

Comment: Are you sure that you pass _attributeSet_ in the parameters and not the whole IEnumerable? _attributeSets_ it is easy to err with only the plural as difference in variable names

Comment: There may well be 3000 infos, but your query only takes two parameters at a time - you'd need to execute it 3000 times. An alternative might be a TVP based query.

Comment: if I was trying to optimize this (reduce the number of parameters), I'd assume that there are more *types* than *colors*. So before getting to the query, I'd group my infos by color, and make the query: `where AnimalTypeID in @AnimalTypeIDs                           and AnimalColorID = @AnimalColorID`, supplying `AnimalTypeIDs` (plural) as a *list* of all the things with that color. Dapper is very good at this kind of `in` substitution - it can even use `string_split` in many cases (but you need to turn that on), which means: only 1 parameter for any number of ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcGravell's suggestion, I decided to rewrite my query as a TVP query.

SQL:

```
create type AnimalInfo as table
( 
    AnimalTypeID int,
    AnimalColorID int
)
go
```

C#:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Animal>> GetAnimalsFromAttributesAsync(DataTable attributeSets)
{
    using (var myDB = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await myDB.OpenAsync();

        var sql = @"select AnimalID, AnimalTypeID, AnimalColor
                    from Animals
                    inner join @animalInfos animalInfos on 
                        animalInfos.AnimalColorID = Animals.ColorID 
                            and 
                        animalInfos.AnimalTypeID = Animals.AnimalTypeID";

        var result = await myDB.QueryAsync<Animal>(sql, new { animalInfos = attributeSets.AsTableValuedParameter("AnimalInfo") };

        return result;
    }
}
```